# A Better understanding on Promise.prototype.then

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

i Have a code something looks like this

```js
function hello(){
     setTimeout(() => console.log("after 3sec"), 3000);
 }
  let x = Promise.resolve()
  x.then(() => {
  hello()
  }).then(() => console.log("after 1st then"))
```

now the output is strange , the console.log in the 2nd then function is getting executed before the console.log in the 1st then .. how to make it synchronous , i mean how can i say that 2nd `.then` should be executed only after the 1st `.then`

Comment: `how to make it synchronous` - you can't ... but you can `return new Promise(resolve =>? setTimeout(resolve, 3000))`  to return a promise that resolves after 3 seconds

Comment: i have edited  the question i want new suggestion

Comment: Did you mean "sequential", not "synchronous"?

Comment: `i want new suggestion` - you still can't make it synchronous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` itself doesn't return a Promise - it's callback-based. If you want to use a callback-based function in a Promise chain, you have to explicitly convert it to a Promise:

```js
let x = Promise.resolve()
x.then(() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("after 500ms");
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });
}).then(() => console.log("after 1st then"))
```

As for your new question, you'll have to make `hello` return a Promise, and then return the `hello` call so it can be chained:

```js
function hello() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("after 500ms");
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });
}
let x = Promise.resolve()
x.then(() => {
  return hello()
}).then(() => console.log("after 1st then"))
```

Comment: `x.then(() => {
  return hello()
})` ... which is simply `x.then(hello)`